# Match text height with image height in menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, for which I put at the end 3 images, measuring 30x30 px each. After the images being inserted, it appeared a space between the bottom line of the menu and only the text. For the image there is no space between the bottom of the menu and the images. What I would like now to do, would be to have the text having the exact size (I managed to fix this space by increasing font size, but this is not a solution for me) as now and get rid of that space. Again, the space is only below the text and not the images. *Check with full-screen the menu.

```css
#nav { 
    background-color: #e26a63;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: FONT;
    font-size: 20px;
}
   
#wrap {
    padding-left: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: bottom;

}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 245px; 
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #cb5f59;
}

#nav ul li:after {
  content: "";
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;

}
#nav ul li:hover:after {
  background: #9e4a45;
}
#nav ul ul li:hover:after {
  background: transparent;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e26a63;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
        z-index: 100;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
#nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.alignright { float: right; }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <div id="wrap">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li><li>

        <a href="#">Study</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Present.html">Present Simple</a></li><li> 
                <a href="Possessives.html">Possesives</a></li><li>  
                <a href="Articles.html">Articles</a></li><li> 
                <a href="Modal.html">Modal Verbs</a></li><li>   
                <a href="Prepositions.html">Prepositions</a></li><li>    
                <a href="Plural.html">Plural of nouns</a></li><li>    
                <a href="Countability.html">Countability</a></li>           
            </ul>
          </li><li>
        <a href="#">Games</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Riddles</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Flip card game</a></li><li>  
                <a href="#">Spot the mistake</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Multiple choice</a></li>                
            </ul>
          </li><li>
        <a href="oferta.html">Shop</a></li><li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li><li>
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a><img src="gmail.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li> <li style="float:right"><a><img src="twitter.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li><li style="float:right"><a><img src="facebook.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest would be to set the same height to your texts as you have on your images

```
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 30px;               /*  added  */
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
#nav { 
    background-color: #e26a63;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: FONT;
    font-size: 20px;
}
   
#wrap {
    padding-left: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: bottom;

}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 245px; 
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #cb5f59;
}

#nav ul li:after {
  content: "";
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;

}
#nav ul li:hover:after {
  background: #9e4a45;
}
#nav ul ul li:hover:after {
  background: transparent;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 30px;               /*  added  */
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e26a63;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
        z-index: 100;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
#nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.alignright { float: right; }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <div id="wrap">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li><li>

        <a href="#">Study</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Present.html">Present Simple</a></li><li> 
                <a href="Possessives.html">Possesives</a></li><li>  
                <a href="Articles.html">Articles</a></li><li> 
                <a href="Modal.html">Modal Verbs</a></li><li>   
                <a href="Prepositions.html">Prepositions</a></li><li>    
                <a href="Plural.html">Plural of nouns</a></li><li>    
                <a href="Countability.html">Countability</a></li>           
            </ul>
          </li><li>
        <a href="#">Games</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Riddles</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Flip card game</a></li><li>  
                <a href="#">Spot the mistake</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Multiple choice</a></li>                
            </ul>
          </li><li>
        <a href="oferta.html">Shop</a></li><li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li><li>
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a><img src="gmail.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li> <li style="float:right"><a><img src="twitter.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li><li style="float:right"><a><img src="facebook.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LSSon, thanks. I've played now a little bit with your solution, it works, but I don't understand why when I increase the image size, everything looks just right. Shouldn't it create that space again?

Comment: @JohnSmith Since you gave the images a fixed width/height they will keep that size no matter what the original size is, and shrink/stretch image to fit the 30px size.